# how to fix ESlint error `module not found` for import `module/module.js` (named directory)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

Given the following file:

```
module/
- module.js
```

if I do `import Module from ./module` it works in javascript (named directory import) but EsLint fails and print:

`Unable to resolve path to module './module'.eslint(import/no-unresolved)`

here is my config for babel and eslint:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "airbnb"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": "webpack"
    }
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "flow",
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
```

Any idea which rule I should activate for EsLint to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you resolving a directory? Can you add more context? Looking at it you say 'module/module.js' and then in your import you see './module' and so as an example this shows one of many ways I can interpret issues in this question.

Comment: @misterhtmlcss I learned today that it is called 'named directory' feature in webpack. https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin